# Does C# 6 make it possible to imply type inference (not explicitly use the var keyword)?

Tags: c#-6.0

This is an odd question, I know.

Earlier this week, I was browsing hacker news and glossed past an article about the power of C# 6. I meant to 'pocket' the link at the time but I didn't and now I can't find the article again.

Long story short, there was an example of code which looked roughly like this...

```
    using static Variables;

    public class Blah
    {
        public Blah()
        {
            s = "something"
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        }
    }
```

... as if to say, somehow it was possible using some magical combination of C# 6 features to remove the 'var' element of that equation and have valid code.

I'm struggling to see how that's possible without some extra Roslyn magic and even then, I'd struggle.

If you know where the article is please let me know. If not, is this even remotely possible? I'm fairly confident it would be an odd thing to do,..I'm just intrigued.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To use `s` you need to declare it first. `public static class Variables { public static string s; }`

Comment: @PetSerAl . That's a good point, I guess that would work. I wonder what was in that (big nasty) class? The article kind of shocked me. I'm not new to the language,..been writing C# for over a decade so I was surprised to see something that looked so impossible to me. It was probably just smoke and mirrors, but you never know....I've been wrong before :-)